# Jquery Cache variables

Tags: jquery, caching

I have the following:

```
$(function(){
   $table = $('#print_types table');
});
```

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
$(function(){
   $($table + ' tr:last > td:first').after('something');
});
```

Since I'm caching a table element, how can I manipulate the table like I showed above? Normally I would have written it like this:

```
$(function(){
   $('div#print_types table tr:last > td:first').after('something');
});
```

The problem is I have a bunch of these statements and is the reason why I cached the table.
 I tried doing what I did, but I get an error. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `.find`:

```
$table.find('tr:last > td:first')
```

This is essentially equivalent.  You can't use `$($table +...` because `$table`'s toString is not the selector you want.

Comment: You're right, I didn't think of using `.find()`. But it works now.
I knew there was something off when I was writing `$($table +...`
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$table` is a jQuery object. A jQuery selector is a string and you can not concatenate a string and an object.

Use `find()` instead

```
 $table.find(' tr:last > td:first').after('something');
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)

```
$table = $('#print_types table');

$('tr:last > td:first', $table).after('something');
```

This is basically the same as

```
$table.find('tr:last > td:first').after('something');
```

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: personally `find()` is easier to read IMO... internally jQuery uses `find()` when context provided so no performance benefits either

Comment: @charlietfl I agree. I am just laying the options out for the OP.

Comment: @charlietfl context is useful when you don't have a jQuery object at your disposal, e.g. `$('selector', this)` vs. `$(this).find('selector')`

Comment: @ExplosionPills  not the case here, and still easier to read `find()` `$(this)` isn't terribly expensive

Comment: @charlietfl I know it's not the case here, I was just pointing it out.  Yes, `$(this)` is not expensive; I'm just saying that they are not necessarily equivalent.

Comment: @ExplosionPills  with exception of an extra `$(this)` call they are essentially the same.. core will use `find()` internally for context and likely has to wrap it in `$(context)`